# What does it mean if a flatpack app is appears in /var/lib/flatpak/app but not in `flatpak list --app`

Tags: flatpak

I recently installed and uninstalled org.gnome.FeedReader but due to some confusion involving GNOME Software I think I might have ended simultaneously installing the flatpak and non-flatpak versions of the package. Or something else, I don't really know what I actually did here.

Anyway, I'm now trying to clean up my mess by uninstalling FeedReader. `flatpak list --app` tells me that the flatpak version of FeedReader has been uninstalled but `locate feedreader` tells me that there are stil a bunch of FeedReader files living under `/var/lib/flatpak/app/org.gnome.FeedReader/`. What gives?

- Is this a flatpak bug or normal behavior (aka my fault)?
- Can I `rm -rf` that directory inside /var/lib/flatpak or is there a better way to clean this up?

I'm currently running Fedora Workstation 30 and flatpak 1.4.2

Answer (score 1):

I have found the same thing on my Mint 19.2 system. It should be safe to delete the aforementioned directory. I would also run `flatpak repair` afterwards, just in case.